# File has copied successfully but condition is behaving wrong in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function to copy files one directory to another in Larave. For that, I've written below code, but the code is behaving wrong.

The function is returning value "1" that is "true" but the condition is behaving something wrong.

```
    public static function copyOneToAnother($source) {
        //Do Something
        $destination = __DIR__."/uploads/testing_another_dir";
        File::makeDirectory($destination);
        return File::copyDirectory($source, $destination);
    }
    public function actionCopy(){
      $source = __DIR__.'/my_project/project1';
      $copy_status = $this->copyOneToAnother($source);  //This is returning true
      if($copy_status === 1){
          echo "Files Copied Successfully";
      }
      else{
          echo "There was an error";
      }

    }
```

This code always showing below results

> There was an error

But files copied successfully and value of `$copy_status` is also 1 even it's going in else loop. I also tried using `trim()` and using true/false in if but didn't work for me.

Comment: If `$copy_status` is returning `true`, then it can not be strictly equal to `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking data type matches then only you are displaying success message but data type there return true not 1 so

```
if($copy_status === 1){
          echo "Files Copied Successfully";
      }
```

if you check like below then it will show success

```
if($copy_status == 1){
          echo "Files Copied Successfully";
      }
```

Instead of comparing with one you can directly check like below so it will treat true

```
 if($copy_status){
          echo "Files Copied Successfully";
      }
      else{
          echo "There was an error";
      }
```

**$a == $b**
Equal   TRUE if `$a` is equal to `$b` after type juggling.

**$a === $b**

Identical   TRUE if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the `same type`.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that `$copy_status` is returning `true`, then it can not be `1` at the same time.

`===` checks for strict equality - `1 == true`, but `1 !== true`.

Also, you could just use

```
if ($copy_status) {
    // do something here
}
```

This is essentially the same as writing `if ($copy_status) == 1`.

More about comparison [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)